# Navigation on Errai-UI based GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm having some problem with Errai-UI based GWT application, trying to create a page with navigation tabs. The problem I face is that the navigation and footer is not being rendered and it seems that my application WelcomePage is the only one being rendered on the browser:

```
@Dependent
@Templated("#home")
@Page(startingPage=true)
public class WelcomePage extends Composite { 
 // stuff
}
```

The associated HTML of the above WelcomePage is the only one being rendered on the browser.

The Bootstrap code:

```
@Templated("#main")
@ApplicationScoped
@EntryPoint
public class Bootstrap extends Composite
{

    @Inject
    Navigation navigation;

    @Inject @DataField
    private NavBar navbar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void buildUI()
    {
        RootPanel.get().add(navigation.getContentPanel());
    }

}
```

And this is the corresponding httml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-field="main">
        <!--top part start -->
        <div id="top">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="individual" width="286" height="66" border="0" /></a>
            <div data-field="navbar">Navbar Goes here</div>
        </div>
        <!--top part end -->

        <div data-field="content"></div>

        <!--footer start -->
        <div id="footerMain">
            <div id="footer">
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a>|</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--footer end -->          
    </div>
    <!-- main end -->
</body>
</html>
```

My application works fine, its just that the navigation and footer is not being rendered. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to do:

```
@PostConstruct
public void buildUI()
{
    content.add(navigation.getContentPanel()); // Just a SimplePanel with data-field in the Bootstrap html
    RootPanel.get("rootPanel").add(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I presume it's because you're only adding actual content panel to the DOM. The DOM is a directed acyclic graph and therefore, cannot have duplicate notes. So when you explicitly add the content panel to the DOM with RootPanel.get().add(navigation.getContentPanel()), the browser is replacing the entire DOM tree with the subtree represented by